# Button hide not working as expected in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, input

Right now its hide and unhide all the rows in a table. I want only the file selected should be shown. Someone could shed some lights on what's missing here? I tried multiple ways still it's breaking my head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id^="rvw-"]').change(
                function(){
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                        alert("(this).val():"+$(this).val());
                        alert("input id:"+ $('input[id^="rvw-"]').val());
                        $('input[id^="rvw-"]').attr('hidden',false); 
                    } 
                }
          );
    });

</script>

<table id="reviewList" class="table table-striped table-condensed dt-responsive basic-table" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Series</th>
            <th class="text-center">Series Order</th>
            <th class="text-center">Document Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${reviewDocList}" var="row">
            <tr>
                <td>${row.series}</td>
                <td>${row.seriesOrder}</td>
                <td>${row.documentName}</td>
                <td>
                    <form class="letter" docId="${row.id}" action='<c:url value="/letter-download.htm?docId=${row.id}"/>' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="docId" value="${row.id}"/>
                        <label class="hidden" for="rvw-${row.id}">Choose file for ${row.documentName}</label>
                        <input type="file" name="doc" id="rvw-${row.id}" title="Choose File for ${row.documentName}"/>
                        <input type="submit"  id="rvw-${row.id}" value="Upload ${row.documentName}" hidden="true"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the selector in the following line :

```
$('input[id^="rvw-"]').attr('hidden',false);
```

The current selector `input[id^="rvw-"]` will target all the inputs that have an `id` start with `rvw-`.

You need to use `$(this)` to refer to the changed file input like :

```
$(this).attr('hidden', false);
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria, it does't  work. Now all buttons are hiding , even after file selection for one row.

Comment: I'm not sure how you test it but a quick check here will show you what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1304/

Comment: Button ids are unique <input type="submit" id="rvw-267" value="">
<input type="submit" id="rvw-268" value="">
<input type="submit" id="rvw-269" value="">

Comment: There's no problem in the id's, they're fine

Comment: From the fiddle I don't see button got unhidden after file selected in first form. Some thing like should be  $('#rvw-$1').attr('hidden', false);  but still didn't work

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here , do you want to disable one at a time, check the following fiddle

Comment: Lets say I have 10 rows in a table , each row as file upload buttons with hide, only on the file selected row buttons should be visible.

Comment: All I want to achieve here is only selected file  should be enable or visible upload button

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `document.querySelector` instead? You won't need JQuery anymore with `element.classList.toggle('classname')`

Just a thought. You can also use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to then convert it to ES5 if you need to.